# Unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Here is my model
**Model**

```
from Account.models import User
from django.db import models

class Seller(models.Model):
    seller = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 90, unique = True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length= 20, unique = True, blank = True, null = True)
    address = models.TextField()
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

**form**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import transaction
from .models import Seller
from Account.models import User

class SellerCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required = True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    phone = forms.CharField(required = False)
    country = forms.CharField(required = True)
    address = forms.CharField(required = True)
    zipcode = forms.CharField(required = True)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_seller = True
        user.name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        user.save()
        seller = Seller.objects.create(user=user)
        seller.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        seller.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        seller.country = self.cleaned_data.get('country')
        seller.address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')
        seller.zipcode = self.cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
        seller.save()
        return user
```

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import SellerCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from Account.models import User

class RegisterSeller(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = SellerCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration/registerseller.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('/')
```

I tried to create a project with multiple users types and all users having different functionality.
**Everything in the code functions well but whenever I try to register a new user I get an error.
And it says Seller() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ForeignKey` from the `Seller` to the `User` has been named `seller`, not <s>`seller`</s>`. You thus can construct an object with:

```
seller = Seller.objects.create(
    seller=user,
    email=self.cleaned_data['email']
    phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
    country = cleaned_data['country']
    address = self.cleaned_data['address']
    zipcode = self.cleaned_data['zipcode']
)
```

But perhaps it is better to rename the field to:

```
from Account.models import User
from django.db import models

class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    # ⋮
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).